# Youtube video showing on top of JS lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, wmode

I've got a Youtube video embedded on my webpage and there's a link below the video which brings up a JavaScript lightbox.

When the lightbox appears, it appears over the lightbox.

Any idea why this is?

The iframe has wmode="transparent" in the parameters which I thought would solve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try and add `wmode="transparent"` to the embed and not just the iframe?

Comment: Thanks, spot on. My mistake - it was the iframe where I had put it.